# nextauth client fetch error, how to handle with it?

Tags: next.js, netlify, next-auth

i have an nextjs application deployed. i decided to include nextAuth in the application.
in localhost, everything works as expect.

but in produce mode, i got a client_fetch_error

`[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]  JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

according to the docs, its a NEXTAUTH_URL issue.

but my .env.local has this key with the value, and in netlify(my app are deployed there)

`NEXTAUTH_URL=https://mydomain.com.br`

in development, this env value are http://localhost:3000 and it works as expect.

i also added my domain to my google's credentials permition.

i dont know what more i can do. how can i fix it?

i expecting to my code works as localhost

Answer (score 1):

You are likely missing `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` environment variables

```js
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://mydomain.com.br
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=EXAMPLE // <-- add this
```

If the issue still occures add this line to your `[...nextauth]` file :

```js
secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
```

> ### Netlify
>
> Netlify is very similar to Vercel in that you can deploy a Next.js project without almost any extra work.
> In order to setup NextAuth.js correctly here, you will want to make sure you add your `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` environment variable in the project settings. If you are using the [Essential Next.js Build Plugin](https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime) within your project, you do not need to set the `NEXTAUTH_URL` environment variable as it is set automatically as part of the build process.
> Netlify also exposes some [system environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/) from which you can check which NODE_ENV you are currently in and much more.
> After this, just make sure you either have your OAuth provider setup correctly with `clientId` / `clientSecret`'s and callback URLs.

Comment: i set all env variable in netlify also, but now i realize that every env.variable in netlify are logging undefined

Comment: do you know why and how can i fix it?